# antd: Force an Input field to Uppercase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

i want the text to be upeercase with ant design, i tried this:

```
<Form form={form} layout='vertical' autoComplete='off'>
    <Form.Item
      name='apellido_empleado'
      label='Apellidos'
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: 'Por favor ingrese los apellidos',
          transform: (v) => v.toUpperCase(),
        },
      ]}>
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
```

it seems that the property transform only work for validations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `onInput` event to transform text to uppercase.

```
const [form] = Form.useForm<{ apellido_empleado: string }>();
return (
    <>
        <Form form={form} layout='vertical' autoComplete='off' sub>
            <Form.Item
                name='apellido_empleado'
                label='Apellidos'
                rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                        message: 'Por favor ingrese los apellidos'
                    },
                ]}>
                <Input onInput={e => e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase()} />
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
        <Button onClick={() => console.log(form.getFieldValue('apellido_empleado'))}>Print value</Button>
    </>
);
```

In typescript `(e.target as HTMLInputElement).value`

Comment: Note that if you want to preserve cursor position you should also set selection range:

```onInput={(event) => {
  const { target } = event;
  if (!(target instanceof HTMLInputElement)) {
    return;
  }
  const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = target;
  Object.assign(target, { value: target.value.toUpperCase() });
  target.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}}
```